# Discord.js ERROR : Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found! Even When Installed

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord, bots, discord.js

Here Is My Screen
[image: My Screen Shot]

```
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.play('./test.mp3');
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
          voiceChannel.leave();
          });   } else {
        message.reply("You Need To Be In A VC To Test This! `;^)`")
    }
```

I Have Both FFmpeg And avconv Installed And Set Up As An Environment Variable.
How Come A Still Get This Error??
And IK That FFmpeg Is Better, I Just Got Avconv Because FFmpeg Wouldn't Work, But Neither Do

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio Code? PATH changes only apply on command line instances created after the change.

Comment: I Have restarted My Whole Computer

Answer (score 0):

Be sure `const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg")` is on top of your code. If it is and the error is still there, you can try to install [ffmpeg-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static) via npm and add it to your file with `const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');`. Hope that helped !

Comment: i just tried const ffmpeg, and i get the same prob, and im using ffmpeg static